# yadcf remove select option before exFilterColumn()

Tags: yadcf

I am trying to remove a select option from an external filter select field using yadcf 0.8.9. In yadcf 0.6.9 I was able to remove this option before the call to `exFilterColumn()`, but in 0.8.9 I must remove the option after the call.

Actually what I am trying to do is force the select to have some value which is in the table column, and to have the table filtered on that value

I can't seem to figure out how to remove the unfiltered possibility from the select and have the table filtered on the chosen value (either the first or one I am picking in the code). In 0.6.9, I removed '-1' value option, but this doesn't seem to work in 0.8.9.

Advice?

See http://codepen.io/louking/pen/ZWYpGM vs http://codepen.io/louking/pen/zqxBLL

html:

```
<div>
  <span id='yadcfext'></span>
</div>
<table id=tbl>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col0</th>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a0</td>
      <td>b0</td>
      <td>c0</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

remove option before exFilterColumn

```
var dt= $('#tbl')
  .dataTable()
  .yadcf([
    {column_number: 0,
     filter_container_id: 'yadcfext'}
  ]);

var selectfilter = '#yadcfext';
$(selectfilter + ' option[value="-1"]').remove();

yadcf.exFilterColumn(dt, [[0,'a1']]);
```

remove option after exFilterColumn()

```
var dt= $('#tbl')
  .dataTable()
  .yadcf([
    {column_number: 0,
     filter_container_id: 'yadcfext'}
  ]);

yadcf.exFilterColumn(dt, [[0,'a1']]);

var selectfilter = '#yadcfext';
$(selectfilter + ' option[value="-1"]').remove();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a new feature :)

So since [0.9.0.beta.9](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/a510f78dfa0246c4897938d4b2e56a9bdbad6743/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js) you can use the [ommit_default_label](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/a510f78dfa0246c4897938d4b2e56a9bdbad6743/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L125) option, see your [codepen in action](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKyEgr)

```
* omit_default_label
    Required:           false
    Type:               boolean
    Default value:      false
    Description:        Prevent yadcf from adding "default_label" (Select value / Select values)
    Note                Currently supported in select / multi_select / custom_func / multi_select_custom_func
```

Comment: cool, thanks! Er, 0.9.0? Just curious about your decision to bump the minor revision number -- are you making any changes to method/function semantics? I got burned a bit from the exFilterColumns() semantics changes in between 0.6.9 and 0.8.8 (not sure when these changed).

Comment: in general I'm trying not to change any existing api functions, but sometimes I'm having no choice and anyway the change is for the better. The minor bumps are per commit / new feature / bug fix and after sometime when I'm in the mood I'm making a big release :)

Comment: heh, should have mentioned this, but omit is not spelled with two m's :)

Comment: what two m's? where? I can't see it, double check it :)